# Twitter bootstrap popover close all before opening a new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not JavaScript wizard, so I'm missing something obvious here I'm sure. I have a unorder-list  that has multiple links & When user do hover on the `<li>` then they can see the link to click on it in order to see  `Twitter Bootstrap's pop-over behavior`.

**My problem is**

- It does not closes previous `pop-over` if i open a new one.
- And also it does show  up again the tweet link if again mouse over on the same "Tweet" image.

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZnJ6b/17/ , please take a look & try to help me.

js code looks like

```
 $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover({
    placement: 'right',
    html: 'true',
    title : '<span class="text-info"><strong>title</strong></span>',
    content : '<input id="subproject_id" type="text"/>'
});

$('.add_btn').click(function(e) {  
          $('.popover-title').append('<button id="popovercloseid" type="button" class="close">&times;</button>');
         $("#subproject_id").focus();//textbox focus
          $(this).css("display","inline");
          $(this).removeClass( "add_btn" ).addClass( "new_add_btn" );
      }); 
  $(document).click(function(e) {    
     if(e.target.id=="popovercloseid" ) { 
          $('.new_add_btn').popover('hide'); 
          $('.new_add_btn').css("display","none");
          $('.new_add_btn').removeClass( "new_add_btn" ).addClass( "add_btn" );

     }

  });
```

http://blog.alysson.net/lang/pt-br/twitter-bootstrap-popover-close-all-before-opening-a-new-one/  is the link seems tutorial, but i am unable to implement it to above code. Any help please?

Comment: I don't see any popvers in the fiddle.

Comment: @knitevision http://jsfiddle.net/ZnJ6b/19/   .. you have to hover on those names to see a "tweet" image & click on it to see popovers

Comment: still don't see anything :)

Comment: @knitevision http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20140413-dfcn-175kb.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code has some unnecessary lines that deflect the behavior of the popover.

I've commented some of the lines and added this statement:

```
$('.add_btn').not(this).popover('hide');
```

so that only one popover is displayed at a time.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnJ6b/21/)**

This bit of code to close your popover with a button:

```
$('html').on('click', '#popovercloseid', function (e) {
        $('.add_btn').not(this).popover('hide'); 
 });
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnJ6b/23/)**

Comment: @Folks Sorry, forgot to check the close button. I've added that part just in case you still need it.

Answer (score 0):

this actually fix the issue:
$('.popover').each(function() { $(this).modal('hide'); });